# How to use SELECT INTO in a plpgsql PROCEDURE?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use [SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-selectinto.html) in a plpgsql procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reset_data()
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS experiment;
SELECT * INTO experiment FROM original;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This results in an error:

```
ERROR:  "experiment" is not a known variable
LINE 5: SELECT * INTO experiment FROM original;
                      ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: "experiment" is not a known variable
SQL state: 42601
Character: 113
```

Apparently, we cannot use SELECT INTO like this.  How do we do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's discouraged to use `select into` to create a table based on a select statement.

It is recommended to use the (standard compliant) [`create table as`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html).

The documentation for `select into` [explicitly mentions PL/pgSQL as one of the reasons](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html#AEN91273):

> `CREATE TABLE AS` is functionally similar to `SELECT INTO`. `CREATE TABLE AS` is the recommended syntax, since this form of `SELECT INTO` is not available in ECPG or PL/pgSQL, because they interpret the `INTO` clause differently

So your function should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reset_data()
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS experiment;
  create table experiment 
  as 
  SELECT * FROM original;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question deserves a better answer even though lots of time has passed.
In order to use the `SELECT INTO` syntax properly, you need to declare your variable first and then assign it a value. Here's an example.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reset_data()
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
   original_extraction record; 
BEGIN
   -- use the SELECT INTO syntax and extract a record
   SELECT *
   INTO original_extraction 
   FROM original
   LIMIT 1;

   -- do whatever with your record
END; $$
```

By declaring the variable, you'll be able to resolve the error *is not a known variable*